# fprintf() function writes last entry to a file indefinitely until I close the program

Tags: c

I tried to run this code, which creates a file and writes some entries until the EOF character is entered.
The problem is when I enter the EOF character, the program writes to the file the last entry indefinitely.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{ 
   unsigned int account; 
   char name[ 30 ]; 
   double balance; 

   FILE *cfPtr;    


   if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "clients.txt", "w" ) ) == NULL ) {
      puts( "File could not be opened" );
   } 
   else { 
      puts( "Enter the account, name, and balance." );
      puts( "Enter EOF to end input." );
      printf( "%s", "? " );
      scanf( "%d%29s%lf", &account, name, &balance );


      while ( !feof( stdin ) ) { 
         fprintf( cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, balance );
         printf( "%s", "? " );
         scanf( "%d%29s%lf", &account, name, &balance );
      } 



      fclose( cfPtr ); // fclose closes file   
   } 
}
```

[input and output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONFPS.png)

[input and output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfJWJ.png)

Comment: It could be that the final attempt at `scanf` is failing to match the format string and isn't consuming anything.  This would leave `stdin` *not* at eof, and would leave your variables unchanged, which would account for what you're seeing.

Comment: You should check the return value from `scanf`.  It should be 3 if it has successfully read the three values.  If it isn't, then you should handle the problem.

Comment: Are you running on Linux (or another Unix system) or on Windows?  Control-D usually indicates EOF on Unix, but on Windows, you use control-Z for the same job.  (On Unix, control-Z normally suspends the program.)

Comment: I am running on cygwin64. It works if I enter control-D 3 times.